# How to set Winston date format string to get microseconds resolution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp, winston

I have the following Winston logger format:

```
simple(),
colorize(),
timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS' })
```

Which gives me timestamps in milliseconds resolution. What should I change in the format string to get the timestamp in microseconds?

Comment: Are you positive this is even possible?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm not sure whether it is event supported. This could be an optional answer to my question :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out microseconds resolution is not supported in Winston. Winston is using [fecha](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) under the hood for timestamp formatting, and fecha does not support microseconds resolution at the moment. I opened the following [github issue](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha/issues/61) requesting fecha to add this feature.